# NextJS / React form useFormStatus not working when passed around components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use "useFormStatus()" hooks in a page.

```
export function SearchForm({
  status
}){
  // const status = useFormStatus()
  return (
    <div>
      ... my form inputs
      <button type="submit" disabled={status.pending} aria-disabled={status.pending} className='btn btn-primary mt-4'>Search</button>
      <div>status.pending?: {status.pending ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
    </div>
  )
}



export default function SearchPage(){  
  const [queryResults, formAction] = useFormState(queryDB, '');
  const status = useFormStatus()

  return (
    <div>
        <form action={formAction}>
      <SearchForm status={status}/>
        <div>status.pending?: {status.pending ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <div>state: {queryResults}</div>
       </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I pas status in from SearchPage(), it never get's updated.
When I define status in the SearchForm (the currently commented out code) it works inside the SearchForm() component.
Neither way is working in the SearchPage() Component.  What am I doing wrong?